# word wrap in select option menu

Tags: html, css

How could I wrap the text inside option menu? I want the option value following the width of the select picker. short text works well, but not with long text.

I have tried many things inside this forum but nothing work. I'm using `bootstrap classes` and no additional `css` yet.

select option menu with short text

[image]

select option menu with long text

[image]

```
  <div class="form-group col-md-5">
                        <label for="programstrategis_id">Program Strategis</label>
                        <select id="programstrategis_id"
                            class="selectpicker data-content form-control @error ('programstrategis_id') is-invalid @enderror"
                            name="programstrategis_id">
                            <option selected disabled>--silahkan pilih program strategis berikut--</option>
                            @foreach ($programstrategis_id as $dataprogramstrategis)
                            <option value="{{ $dataprogramstrategis->id }}">{{$dataprogramstrategis->program_strategis}}
                            </option>

                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                        @error('programstrategis_id')
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            {{ $message }}
                        </div>
                        @enderror
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-5">
                        <label for="sasaran_id">Sasaran</label>
                        <select id="sasaran_id"
                            class="selectpicker form-control @error ('sasaran_id') is-invalid @enderror"
                            name="sasaran_id">
                            <option selected disabled>--silahkan pilih sasaran berikut--</option>
                            @foreach ($sasaran_id as $datasasaran)
                            <option value="{{ $datasasaran->id }}">{{$datasasaran->sasaran}}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                        @error('sasaran_id')
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            {{ $message }}
                        </div>
                        @enderror
                    </div>
```

Comment: You can't word wrap a native select tag but you can use jquery plugins

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm using bootstrap classes and no additional css yet.

Since you're using bootstrap, you can create dropdown using `<div>` or `<a>` tag instead of `<select>`. It's easier to wrap the text inside.

You can set the default width for `dropdown-menu` class and update `white-space` property for all of the child items `.dropdown-item`.

```css
.dropdown-menu {
  width: 170px;
}

.dropdown-menu .dropdown-item {
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here Something else here Something else here Something else here Something else here Something else here Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Using only CSS, manually wrap the text, as required. Note the options used for the wrapped text are 'disabled' so only the 'titles' can be selected, but this can be undone if required.

```
    <select style="width: 150px;">
    <option selected="selected" disabled>Wrap Demo</option>
    <option>-- All --</option>
    <option>Title A</option>
    <option disabled>&nbsp;&nbsp;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, </option>
    <option disabled>&nbsp;&nbsp;sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </option>
    <option>Title B</option>
    <option disabled>&nbsp;&nbsp;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, </option>
    <option disabled>&nbsp;&nbsp;sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </option>
    <option>Title C</option>
    <option disabled>&nbsp;&nbsp;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, </option>
    <option disabled>&nbsp;&nbsp;sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </option>
    </select>
```

[image: select wrap text example]